# How to pass an uncertain number of php variables through JQUERY / AJAX

Tags: jquery

Please, look at this PHP script (sendingpage.php):

```
$i=1;

While(whatever){

echo "<input id='ref".$i."' type='hidden' value='".$variable."' />";
echo "<input id='ref2".$i."' type='hidden' value='".$variable2."' />";
$i++;

}
```

Now, what I want to do is passing all values to another php page (receivingpage.php) using the JQUERY AJAX method and after processing the received data in receivingpage.php loading the result in my sendingpage.php. Note that I do not know how many cicles this script will generate nor what values $variable and $variable2 will hold at each cicle.

I think I can go through all the final loading thing, but where I'm having troubles is at passing all values from sending.php to receiving.php using AJAX/JQUERY

I hope any of you throw some light on it for me. I would be really grateful.

Comment: To grab all fields in a form you'd use `$('form').serialize()` to generate something in the format `myField=fieldVal`

Comment: Thanks, techie_28 and Tom Walters. Shall I unserialize when receiving the data in receivingpage.php? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is inside a `<form>` then you can use `serialize` function to pass it as a data in ajax call.
like

```
$.ajax({
     type :'POST',
     data:$('#formId').serialize();
     ...so on
})
```

It is also recomended to set type to post as it will allow you to send it as post request and will send all form fields in the request.

Comment: Thanks, techie_28 and Tom Walters.  Shall I unserialize when receiving the data in receivingpage.php?

Comment: @techie_28 no worries! And you'll be able to access your variables in the form `$_GET['varName']`

Comment: It will be `$_POST` in this case as type has been set to `POST`